# Sql: Using special characters as alias for table columns?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Can I use any special character as alias name for my table column.

for e.g.: `select id as #,first_name,last_name from student;`

Comment: What happens if you try?

Comment: ORA-00911: invalid character

Comment: @MusakkhirSayyed - I don't see how that is a duplicate; this isn't about using a double-quote character as part of the alias? That is a different level of problem to using other 'special' characters like #.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to use [a quoted identifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223):

```
select id as "#",first_name,last_name from student
```

You are allowed a # in an unquoted object name (which includes aliases), from object naming rule 7:

> Nonquoted identifiers can contain only alphanumeric characters from your database character set and the underscore (_), dollar sign ($), and pound sign (#). Database links can also contain periods (.) and "at" signs (@). Oracle strongly discourages you from using $ and # in nonquoted identifiers.
>
> Quoted identifiers can contain any characters and punctuations marks as well as spaces. However, neither quoted nor nonquoted identifiers can contain double quotation marks or the null character (\0).

But not as a single character name, because of rule 6:

> Nonquoted identifiers must begin with an alphabetic character from your database character set. Quoted identifiers can begin with any character.

Comment: Just in case, in SQL*Plus, you could use `heading`.

Comment: @LalitKumarB - true, but that isn't a column alias *8-) Works in SQL Developer too though.

Answer (score 3):

You could use **quoted-idetifier** i.e. **double-quotation marks** around the alias.

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129),

> Database Object Naming Rules
>
> Every database object has a name. In a SQL statement, you represent
>   the name of an object with a quoted identifier or a nonquoted
>   identifier.
>
> - A quoted identifier begins and ends with double quotation marks ("). If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, then you
>     must use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object.
> - A nonquoted identifier is not surrounded by any punctuation.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT empno as "#" FROM emp WHERE ROWNUM <=5;

         #
----------
      7369
      7499
      7521
      7566
      7654

SQL>
```

Alternatively, in **SQL*Plus** you could use the **HEADING** command.

For example,

```
SQL> column empno heading #
SQL> SELECT empno FROM emp WHERE ROWNUM <=5;

         #
----------
      7369
      7499
      7521
      7566
      7654

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Special Characters That Can Be Used in the Alias Name Field

```
Character
!
#
$
%
&
'
*
+
_
/
=
?
^
_
.
{
|
}
~
```

In oracele , double quotes can be used. I tried and working well in Toad.
In SQL , heading keyword can be used as mentioned by others in answers as well.

Comment: "Nonquoted identifiers can contain only alphanumeric characters from your database character set and the underscore (_), dollar sign ($), and pound sign (#)" - the rest aren't valid unless you use a quoted identifier, and you can't use any of these as the first (or only) character in an unquoted name.

Comment: this is what i said that alone they cannot be used alone. I use toad where if i use double quotes , it can be used alone as well but in some of the database it is not allowing ( we have to use heading )

Comment: Every other character works fine except for the "&". 
I trying to alias a column: SELECT numberofemployees "Employess (D&B) from account;
This query is prompting me to give a value for a variable.
I am using it in PL/SQL Deveploer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of doublequotes for defining special characters as alias.
Tried and tested:

```
SELECT CustomerName AS Customer, ContactName AS "*" FROM Customers;
```